# Advantage of Deploying AngularJS application with Restful services on diffeent servers

Tags: angularjs, rest, tomcat7

I want to deploy angularJs app on somw web server and restful services on application servers like tomcat.

Can any one please let me know that what will be the advantage and disadvantages of deploying angularJs app with Restful services on different server  or on same servers.

which option will be good including authorization and performance.

Comment: What are the other options you have considered ?

Answer (score 2):

Since the html / angularjs code will be downloaded on the clients devices and then the webservice will be called by those clients there is no gain on the response time if the app and the ws are on the same server.

For the rest, it all depends on the load of your website. Distributing the html code to the clients does not take that much of a load, but you will have an apache (or ngix or wathever) + a tomcat + your database running on the same server, it will be ok for most cases, it depends on the success of your website but usually when you have to ask yourself how you are going to manage such a load you have the means to rethink the architecture!

The most important is to have your db and your tomcat on the same server!

For the authorizations, if you use a REST webservice you will have to deal with those damn CORS headers whether or not the app and the ws are on the same server.

Overall, having 2 servers will be more flexible and share the load more evenly but it will also increase the cost, so you will probably be fine with only one!

Comment: I want to user NodeJs for AngularJs deployment and Tomcat server for Rest web services  with Oracke Database. Will it be a good ??

Comment: It all depends on the expected load my friend. If you notice that the server is overloaded you will just just have to put the server + db on an other server, no big deal!

What matters is that you have the db and the webservice on the same server / local network.